# Why is this a "cannot find symbol" error?

Tags: java

I'm finishing up my project but keep running into  this error. I don't get it because PermutationData is another class with static String[][] ROTOR_SPECS (an array) and i'm checking to see if the element x[0] is inside PermutationData but my compiler keeps recognizing PermutationData as a a variable not a class.... I'm inside my Rotor class right now.

Rotor.java:90: error: cannot find symbol

```
for (String[] x : PermutationData.ROTOR_SPECS) {
                  ^
symbol: variable PermutationData
location: class Rotor
        if (type() == x[0]) {
            Index1 = toIndex(x[1].charAt(p));
```

This is my PermutationData.java class.

```
class PermutationData {

/** The names and definitions of the rotors and reflectors in M4.  The
 *  first string in each entry is the name of a rotor or reflector.  The
 *  second is a 26-character string whose first character is the mapping
 *  (when the rotor is at the 'A' setting), of 'A' in the right-to-left
 *  direction, whose second is that of 'B', etc.
 *
 *  The third entry, if present, is the inverse of the
 *  second---the left-to-right permutation of the rotor.  It is
 *  not present for reflectors.
 *
 *  The fourth entry, if present, gives the positions of the
 *  notches. These are the settings of the rotors just before the
 *  wheels advanced (wheels advance before a character is
 *  translated).  Other written accounts of the Enigma generally
 *  show instead the character settings just after a character is
 *  coded (e.g., 'R', rather than 'Q', or 'A' rather than 'Z').
 *  The entry is absent in rotors that do not advance. */

static final String[][] ROTOR_SPECS = {
    { "I", "EKMFLGDQVZNTOWYHXUSPAIBRCJ", "UWYGADFPVZBECKMTHXSLRINQOJ",
      "Q" },
    { "II", "AJDKSIRUXBLHWTMCQGZNPYFVOE", "AJPCZWRLFBDKOTYUQGENHXMIVS",
      "E" },
    { "III", "BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO", "TAGBPCSDQEUFVNZHYIXJWLRKOM",
      "V" },
    { "IV", "ESOVPZJAYQUIRHXLNFTGKDCMWB", "HZWVARTNLGUPXQCEJMBSKDYOIF",
      "J" },
    { "V", "VZBRGITYUPSDNHLXAWMJQOFECK", "QCYLXWENFTZOSMVJUDKGIARPHB",
      "Z" },
    { "VI", "JPGVOUMFYQBENHZRDKASXLICTW", "SKXQLHCNWARVGMEBJPTYFDZUIO",
      "ZM" },
    { "VII", "NZJHGRCXMYSWBOUFAIVLPEKQDT", "QMGYVPEDRCWTIANUXFKZOSLHJB",
      "ZM" },
    { "VIII", "FKQHTLXOCBJSPDZRAMEWNIUYGV", "QJINSAYDVKBFRUHMCPLEWZTGXO",
      "ZM" },
    { "BETA", "LEYJVCNIXWPBQMDRTAKZGFUHOS", "RLFOBVUXHDSANGYKMPZQWEJICT" },
    { "GAMMA", "FSOKANUERHMBTIYCWLQPZXVGJD", "ELPZHAXJNYDRKFCTSIBMGWQVOU" },
    { "B", "ENKQAUYWJICOPBLMDXZVFTHRGS" },
    { "C", "RDOBJNTKVEHMLFCWZAXGYIPSUQ" }
};
```

}

Comment: if ROTOR_SPECS is a method, aren't you supposed to use braces after it?

Answer (score 3):

If `ROTOR_SPECS` is indeed a method, you should call it using brackets: `PermutationData.ROTOR_SPECS()`

otherwise the compiler thinks it's a variable!

Comment: i did that but now eclipse is red lining ROTOR_SPECS() saying  the method ROTOR_SPECS() is not defined for type PermutationData

Comment: If `PermutationData` is a class, and `ROTOR_SPECS` is not defined as a static method - you can call it only after you create an instance of the class!

Comment: static final String[][] ROTOR_SPECS

Comment: In your question you wrote "class with a **method** ROTOR_SPECS" and now you write that it's declared as a static variable. Better post all the relevant code and what is exactly the error that you get from the compiler.

Comment: Also, these two classes are in the same package ? if not - did you import class `PermutationData` ?

Comment: These are in the same directory called enigma it's a school project. I should've specified that ROTOR_SPECS was a static final variable . I'm still confused as to why the compiler recognizes PermutationData as a variable and import PermutationData; doesn't work on my Rotor class

Comment: did you write `import PermutationData.java` as the first line in Rotors class ? Like I already wrote - if you don't post your code - it's impossible to debug it...

Comment: pacakage enigma; is the first line in all my classes so i don't think that's the issue.

Comment: i posted my code for permutationdata. they're both part of pacakage enigma;

Comment: The compiler doesn't "recognize" class `PermutationData` from inside `Rotor`. I tried a code similar to yours and it worked for me just fine. Meaning, there must be something that you're not showing us: class Rotor, directory structure, how do you compile your classes etc.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the answer by @alfasin, make sure that you have imported PermutationData

Comment: how would i go about importing another class into this class

Comment: That depends on package structure you follow. If you have both `Rotor` class and `PermutationData` in same package, you need not import it. Otherwise, if you not using any IDE like Eclipse, make sure, you import it with an import statement manually.

Comment: they're both part of the package enigma; so i don't think ineed to import anything. I don't understand why the compiler keeps recognizing  PermutationData as a variable it's a FREAKING CLASS

Answer (score 0):

I think that your PermutationData.java class has default level package access and you are calling it from some other package.Because of this  PermutationData.java class can't be accessed.

Please make  PermutationData.java public that can solve your problem.

Another thing is yes ROTOR_SPECS is a variable of type String[][].So you can first store it somewhere in your program and assign it to some other variable and then check for its existence.

Try and run this.It is working.

```
for (String[] x : PermutationData.ROTOR_SPECS) {  
             System.out.println(x[0]);
}
```